# Chart with top rounded bars and average line in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, graph

I want to create charts displayed in the image below.

> whenever I will click a particular bar value list value, should get highlighted
> bar top corner should be rounded
> need to display average line over the bars in dashed view

I'm not able to find suitable lib with same design pattern.

[Please see the design in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e1uc.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to create a view with top rounded view? Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Did you find a solution for the average line?

Answer (score 0):

for rounded view you have to give a style. I guess it will  work.

```
   style={{
      margin: 10,
      height: 200,
      width: 20,
      borderTopRightRadius: 10,//for rounded curve
      borderTopLeftRadius: 10,// for rounded curve.
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    }}
```

I made a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-morning-kjezx?file=/src/App.js:191-384) please have a look,